# Syncmaster 225W repair / new capacitors

Tags: external-display, repair

I recently replaced 5 capacitors in my Syncmaster 225BW after it was having severe issues maintaining steady output. I referred to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLrrcKdJLyw) for the instruction and replaced the capacitors as demonstrated: 3 x 330uF & 2 x 820uF. Usually includes but missing from [my kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0053DAP3Q) was one of the smaller 47uF capacitors.

After said replacement, the monitor performs well with a steady output, though still has a serious issue powering back on after using the power button the front bezel. There is also a faint amount of ghosting present, most noticeably when moving the cursor over a white background. Another hint is that the display emits a not insignificant amount of buzzing when the brightness is turned down.

Difficulty powering on is often known to be a capacitor issue though I am not sure if the ghosting is solved the same way. Is it worth trying the same repair with the full set including the smallest 47uF capacitor and possibly also the largest capacitor not included in any kits I've seen? Or is there another front I ought pursue in the restoration effort of this monitor?

Comment: Ghosting may be due to long or bad video cables. Also, check the rectifiers that feed the capacitors; one bad rectifier in a bridge can damage caps and cause buzzing.

Comment: Cross posting is frowned upon.  Same question is on ee.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/267099

Comment: Gee whiz, I wasn't sure what forum was appropriate, but it seems clear neither forum has much expertise on LCD repair .. can anyone recommend somewhere most appropriate for this inquiry?